# How to correctly use returned array with Jquery (ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Php function :

```
public function getThreadsbyNumber($number) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `threads` LIMIT $number");
    while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $threads[] = $fetch;
    }
    return $threads;
}
```

Ajax url file :

```
require_once '../Classes/MainController.php';
$mc = MainController::getInstance();
$result = $mc->getThreadsbyNumber(5);
foreach ($result as $thread) {
print json_encode($thread['url']);
}
```

the print returns the following (which are valid video id's):

```
"UjN_aX84Qco""lB6K60mkmho""ReRcHdeUG9Y""aXD6prwrYGw""b6pvDKjp-_s"
```

Up until now everything is working great. This is the html in which the output of the jquery function will go :

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="large-3 small-6 columns">
            <a class="th" id="small_th_1"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500&text=LEL_Error"></a>
            <div class="panel">
                <p id="small_th_1_description">Description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to add between  here  an iframe based on the video id provided by the php file but I can't get the jquery function to work. This is the jquery function :

```
   function getThreadsbyNumber() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "Ajax/getThreadsbyNumber.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        $('#mainHeadline').html('<iframe width="320" height="240" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'+data[0]+'?autoplay=1" frameborder="0""></iframe>');
        $('#small_th_1').html('<iframe width="320" height="240" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'+data[1]+'?autoplay=1" frameborder="0""></iframe>');
        $('#small_th_2').html('<iframe width="320" height="240" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'+data[2]+'?autoplay=1" frameborder="0""></iframe>');
        $('#small_th_3').html('<iframe width="320" height="240" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'+data[3]+'?autoplay=1" frameborder="0""></iframe>');
        $('#small_th_4').html('<iframe width="320" height="240" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'+data[4]+'?autoplay=1" frameborder="0""></iframe>');
    }

    });
    }
```

Comment: Not sure I get it, but when you echo the JSON in a loop, you're echoing several JSON parts, and me thinks you end up with something that isn't really valid JSON.

Comment: You are inputting a 5 in the function. Declare that var in the function too.

Comment: @adeneo So , do you have any suggestions how it should be done ?

Comment: you can use json_encode directly on $result variable

Comment: Yeah but , a $thread is formed of a string with more variables , and i am interested only in $thread['url']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to split the JSON string into bits and send it chunk-by-chunk. The whole idea of JSON is that it allows you to encode entire objects and/or arrays into **one** string.

Instead of

```
$result = $mc->getThreadsbyNumber(5);
foreach ($result as $thread) {
    print json_encode($thread['url']);
}
```

try just sending it as one string:

```
$result = $mc->getThreadsbyNumber(5);
print json_encode($result);
```

You can then access it like so (in your AJAX callback):

```
success: function(data) {
    //data.length - the number of $threads (which you were originally sending back one-by-one)
    //data[0] - the first thread
    //data[0][0] - the first field in the first thread
    //for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) - loop through each thread
    //for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) - loop through each field from thread 1
}
```

These are of course just examples. Play around with how you structure your JSON to find the best way to go for your situation. But either way, **one** AJAX request should give **one** response. That response can be a single thread or an array of many, but it should be **one** JSON encoded string.
Also, use a [JSON validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to make sure the JSON you are getting is valid.

Comment: Do you think 
foreach ($result as $thread) {
    parse_str($thread['url'], $urls);
}
would work ? or am I just getting more tangled ?

Comment: It worked Perfectly , thanks for the ajax part , really well explained

Answer (score -1):

In your ajax file:

```
$json = '[';
foreach ($result as $thread) {
    $json += $thread['url'];
}
$json += ']';
echo $json;
```

your returning string should be like:

```
["UjN_aX84Qco","lB6K60mkmho","ReRcHdeUG9Y","aXD6prwrYGw","b6pvDKjp-_s"]
```

Comment: `json_encode` is more suitable. I bet your code will not work for multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: we aren't in this case, but you are 100% right.
I wanted to say : do one echo or print, on the wanted data.

Comment: Your code actually returns 0 (zero) , like the number 0 , because like @afaolek said , $result is actually a multi-dimensional array.